# php strpos not working with boolean or

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a condition that if there isn't the arguments "views" or "ckeditor" in the url, execute an echo on the page. The code that I am using and is not working is this:

```
    <pre>
     <?php

     $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   //if (!strpos($url,'views')) {

     if ((!strpos($url,'views')) OR (!strpos($url,'ckeditor'))) {

     echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>'   } 

  else {
echo '';
}
?>
</pre>
```

What is wrong in my script?

Comment: Use strstr to make it work with booleans, because strpos returns integers.

Comment: You must compare `strpos()` with `!== false` to verify non-presence of the needle string. It returns zero (which is falsy) if the string is in the first position.

Comment: Please use the correct boolean operator.   [`or` has a different precedence than `||`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and they cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Please don't use strstr for needle in the haystack searches. It is slow and computationally expensive compared to using strpos, which should always be used with strict checking. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) returns `FALSE` if the string is not found, and `0` if it is found at the beginning. In this case, you're trying to check if the URL contains either of these strings. So, you can simply check if it returns `FALSE`:

```
if ((strpos($url,'views') === FALSE) && (strpos($url,'ckeditor') === FALSE)) {
```

The above `if` condition will evaluate to `TRUE` if the URL doesn't contain `views` and `ckeditor` strings. If you only want to check for the existence of either one of the strings, then you can change `&&` to `||`.

Answer (score 0):

a return value of 0 from `strpos` is a truthy response, however you are not checking for that. You should use `strpos($url,'views') !== false`

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this part have a semicolon

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>'
```

like this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>';
```

only thing at first glance i noticed

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing them thru a GET parameter you better use either $_GET or $_REQUEST instead of checking the url.

But if that's not the case, you may do something like:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strrpos($url, "views") === false || strrpos($url, "ckeditor") === false) {
...
}
```

Note for the 3 equal signs