# PHP type juggling with strpos() conditions and ||, in spite of strict ===?

Tags: php, casting, strpos

Except for two files (`bg177b_s.php` and `bg177b_t.php`) a headline shall be added.  In other words, if neither of the two `strpos()` conditions matches, something shall be done, else nothing.

I got this to work two ways, provided that `strpos()` won't evaluate to `0`. In the latter case it seems PHP juggles the integer `0` to `FALSE` in spite of the strict `===` operator. However, as plenty as there are pages for all sorts of juggling effects, I could not find one matching this scenario.

[PHP strpos not working with boolean or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076638/php-strpos-not-working-with-boolean-or) comes close in that it resembles my third solution, but not explains why it won't work with the `strpos()` conditions bracketed into a `||` statement.

Anyway, I shall be grateful to any guidance, most likely my logic's hit a block somewhere.

This is with PHP 5.3.5. For technical reasons no update to any later version is possible at this moment in case the behaviour is just a bug and not a misunderstanding of mine.

```
// works (evaluates to FALSE||FALSE or FALSE||9):

if ((strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'bg177b_s') ||
    strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'bg177b_t')) === false) {
        // do something
}


// so does this (evaluating to FALSE||FALSE or FALSE||1):

$thispage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // eg /hunting/bg177bXX.php
if ((strpos($thispage, 'g177b_s') ||
    strpos($thispage, 'g177b_t')) === false) {
        // do something
}


// works, but seems clumsy and a waste of resources:

if (strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_s') === false &&
    strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_t') === false) {
        // do something
}


// doesn't work as expected (evaluates to either FALSE||FALSE [then it works] or
// FALSE||0 [then 0 is seemingly cast as FALSE which is against what is wanted],
// both bg177b_s and bg177b_t are dealt with as being false)

if ((strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_s') ||
    strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_t')) === false) {
        // do something
}


// doesn't work for bg177b_s (=== seemingly takes precedence over ||)

if (strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_s') ||
    strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_t') === false) {
        // do something
}
```

**Edit:**

Looking into @halfer's helper function I wondered if instead of the `foreach` loop an `in_array` or even `array_key_exists` would not be more direct, given there already is an array for the needles.

Doing some research with regard to efficiency - i. a. [Efficiency of Searching an Array vs Searching in Text… Which is Better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325128/efficiency-of-searching-an-array-vs-searching-in-text-which-is-better) - resulted in an *It depends*.

Anyway, Seldaek's suggestion there made me flip the original `$haystack` and `$needle` here, resulting in one `strpos` operation only:

```
if (strpos('bg177b_s.php, bg177b_t.php', $thispage) === false)
```

The price is, of course, that either as array keys or in the haystack string filenames have to be at least as complete as `$thispage` must be expected to return, otherwise it won't work or require an additional `substr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not down to a PHP bug. Here is the issue:

```
strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_s') || strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_t')
```

You are doing a `strpos` on both strings, and then doing an `OR` on the result. That forces the result to be boolean, which loses the difference between zero and false.

Put another way, if one of these functions returns zero, it means that one of the strings was found at the 0th position. This gets logical-ored with false (since presumably both won't occur at the same time) giving you an incorrect false result.

Your third code example is the correct one:

```
strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_s') === false &&
strpos($thispage, 'bg177b_t') === false
```

I would be inclined to use a helper function, which simplifies the call:

```
function findOneString($haystack, array $needles)
{
    $found = false;
    foreach($needles as $needle)
    {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false)
        {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

You can call this with:

```
findOneString($thispage, array('bg177b_s', 'bg177b_t', ));
```

Comment: I was thinking in that direction, but wherever PHP juggling showed along with ´OR´ / ´||´, the casting was on the assignment/comparison side.  Indeed for simple ´OR´s there seems to be no absolute necessity for type casting.  The idea was, of course, to minimize the number of comparison operations, though solutions 1 & 2 had the smell of a hack.  ´preg_match´, ´glob´ and ´fnmatch´ were considered to be too big guns to shoot just two files out of a bunch of 50+.

Comment: Thanks for the helper function, too.  In this case it probably makes not much of a difference, but going on reviewing some old code it may well come very handy. Besides sorry for the late reply, just couldn't get my head around to this matter again recently.